# Which managed services OSS provides the most viable remote script execution?

Tags: script, open-source, unattended, remote-execution, managed

I've came across four open source managed IT services software that allow for **remote script execution**. However, I am unable to find the amount of detail or power of these remote script execution capabilities.

The four tools we are considering using are either ZenOSS, OpsView, Zabbix, or Hyperic HQ. We need the scripts to be able to run when we tell them to (or automatically). We need the capability for the scripts to install or remove software. Basically there must be a capability to create scripts that can do things **unattended**.

Do either of these four tools have this capability? If so, which ones?

Comment: What's your target OS/environment for the clients being managed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question; we use `puppet`.